# GWT compatibility with JDK 7 new features

Tags: java, gwt, java-7

For example, JDK 7 is capable of switch(String) rather than just switch(Number/Enum).

If I wrote a GWT client that has switch(String) in its code, will there be any problems?

switch(String) is one of the issues I can think of. Are there compatibility issues beyond switch(String)?

Comment: @OliverWeiler: nothing wrong with asking even if you can find it out yourself. this question/answer saved me lots of time.

Comment: You can always compile with JDK7, but not use the features. That remains an option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GWT only officially supports Java 5. It does support a few of Java 6 though, such as allowing `@Overrides` on methods implementing an interface method, and `String.isEmpty` (though that one is about the runtime emulation, so it's not related to syntax and the compiler).

BTW, GWT uses Eclipse JDT for parsing, and that one hasn't yet been released with support for Java 7 (should come [really soon](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_7_Support_%28BETA%29) though). Once that's done, GWT would have to be updated to take into account the new "syntax sugar" added by Java 7. When that time come (which probably won't come anytime soon, alas), I bet switch-on-strings will be one of the first supported features, given that JavaScript supports it (so it should be as easy to translate from Java to JS as a switch on an integer).

See also https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/dM8D9imIvAI/discussion

Comment: I believe that Java 6 is officially supported.

Comment: Some of Java 7 may be be supported in the future. See,  https://gwt-review.googlesource.com/#/c/2650/ and https://gwt-review.googlesource.com/#/c/2681/)

Answer (score 11):

As the last answer is from August 2011, here's an update for GWT 2.5: still no support for Java 7, see [Release Notes for GWT 2.5 RC2](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/release-notes#Release_Notes_2_5_0_RC2) (no change from RC2 to 2.5 final).

Comment: It seems so. I wanted to try using java.util.Objects instead of Guava's one, but GWT choked on it, although the class is in the official white list. Unless I missed something in the configuration...

Comment: Here is an update: development is already in progress, see issue#7999 for details. A few days ago all Java 7 features were commited and passed for review. Runtime emulation still needs some work.

See: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7999

Comment: Another update, following the link from @snorbi : https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8044#c10 from  Sept. 11 seems to mark Java 7 support as "FixedNotReleased" for "Milestone-2_6"

Answer (score 2):

Starting from GWT 2.6

> Java 7 is supported and is now the default. (This can be overridden
>   using 
>   -sourceLevel 6)

[2.6 release notes](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_0)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Java 7 support](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7999) is coming in GWT 2.6. As of today, the project has three release candidates [available for download](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/list). I'm going to wait for the official release.